# React Native - Conditional Styles on Parent Based on Child State

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was following the React Native tutorial and have tried to adapt it to show a list of songs rather than movies and add in a toggling ability using the `Switch` component.

I managed to get this to work but now I am trying to send the value of the switch back to the parent so that a conditional style can be applied.

When I attempted to do this, I get an error saying

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.played')
```

which seems sensible since the `console` statement in the `togglePlayed` never seems to be called.

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Switch
} from 'react-native';

var SONGS_DATA = {
  "songs" : [
    {
      "title" : "I Heard React Was Good",
      "artist" : "Martin",
      "played" : false
    },
    {
      "title" : "Stack Overflow",
      "artist" : "Martin",
      "played" : false
    }
  ]
}

var BasicSwitchExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      played: false
    };
  },
  handlePlayed(value) {
    console.log('Switch has been toggled, new value is : ' + value)
    this.setState({played: value})
    this.props.callbackParent(value);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View> 
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.handlePlayed}
          style={{marginBottom: 10}}
          value={this.state.played} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      played: false
    };
  }

  togglePlayed(value) {
    // this is never reached
    this.setState({played: value});
    console.log('Song has been played? ' + this.state.played);
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(SONGS_DATA.songs),
      loaded: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderSong}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading songs...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderSong(song) {
    return (
      // not sure if this syntax is correct
      <View style={this.state.played ? 'styles.container' : 'styles.played'}>
        <View style={styles.half}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{song.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.artist}>{song.artist}</Text> 
        </View>
        <View style={styles.half}>
          <BasicSwitchExample callbackParent={() => this.togglePlayed} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  /* styles here */
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

[React Native Playground](https://rnplay.org/apps/mnanvw)

Any pointers would be great as I am new to React and especially React Native.

Comment: you should remove the styles and the songs in order to make it easier to read :P

Comment: yeah, obviously those songs aren't the real data, I truncated it to two made up examples to try and get some brevity. I can remove them, I just thought it would be better to include them.

Comment: I guess that your problem is that you have not binded togglePlayed to your component, you forgot to bind it in the constructor, at least thats how it works in React(I don't know about React native tho!)

Comment: @QoP I have noticed the use of `bind` when reading other questions about passing state from child to parent components but one example I seen didn't use it so I'm a bit confused when it's required and when it's not. If you have a solution I'd gladly mark it accepted if you have time to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to bind your function to your component, it should look like this

```
class BasicSwitchExample extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         played: false
       };
      this.handlePlayed = this.handlePlayed.bind(this);
    }
    handlePlayed(value){
        this.setState({played: value});
        this.props.callbackParent(value);
    }
    render() {
      return <View> 
        <Switch
          onValueChange={this.handlePlayed}
          style={{marginBottom: 10}}
          value={this.state.played} />
      </View>
  }
}
class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderSong = this.renderSong.bind(this);
    this.togglePlayed = this.togglePlayed.bind(this); 
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  togglePlayed(value) {
    // this is never reached
    this.setState({played: value});
    console.log('Song has been played? ' + this.state.played);
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(SONGS_DATA.songs),
      loaded: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderSong}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading songs...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderSong(song) {
    return (
      // not sure if this syntax is correct
      <View style={this.state.played ? 'styles.container' : 'styles.played'}>
        <View style={styles.half}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{song.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.artist}>{song.artist}</Text> 
        </View>
        <View style={styles.half}>
          <BasicSwitchExample callbackParent={this.togglePlayed} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @QoP, seems to be the same error though (https://rnplay.org/apps/mnanvw). If the conditional style is removed, then the console logging from `togglePlayed` still doesn't seem to be reached, do you have any ideas?.

Comment: The comment I wrote made no sense, I didn't see that you were using ES5 syntax, anyway try to write them both in ES6 syntax

Comment: hmm, being new to this I am unsure, that's why I put `getInitialState` in the switch component so that `played` was initialised to `false`. Are you able to update the answer with your suggestion? I'll give it a try in the meantime.

Comment: I added the BasicSwitch component

Comment: thank you very much. The error I get now is `'this' is not allowed before super()`. Just taking a look just now to see if I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It's because I forgot to write super(props) in the constructor :P, already edited

Comment: ah, thanks again, I really appreciate it. I don't want to keep harassing you but it's back at the original error ( `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.played')` for the conditional styles.)

Comment: you have to add renderSong to your constructor too, because you are using this in renderSong and this is not defined there(because its not binded). Also you got to bind fetchData :P

Comment: thank you. Please don't shoot me, but I now get `BasicSwitchExample.render(): A valid React Component must be returned, you have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110078/discussion-between-qop-and-martincarlin87).